# Reasons a variable can be undefined on iPad vs. being defined in my Browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, web-applications, undefined

I'm clueless.

In my Jquery Mobile Plugin I'm declaring:

```
var $currentEntry = $.mobile.urlHistory.stack[$.mobile.urlHistory.activeIndex].url;
    $activePage = $('div:jqmData(url="'+ $currentEntry +'")');
```

So I'm taking the active page's url and use it to construct an $activePage object.

This works fine on desktop, but on my iPad (iOS3.3), **$currentEntry** is defined correctly, but **$activePage** is *undefined*.

**Question:**
What can be reasons for this?

You can rule out race conditions, because wrapping this in a 10sec timeout still produces the same result. Also, if I console the respective page directly and query it's **data-url**, it shows the correct value. So how come the above still gives me undefined on iOS

```
 undefined
```

while working correctly everywhere else?

Thanks for any hints!

**EDIT**:
The element will be dynamic, but I can console for the page in my setup directly like so:

```
console.log( $('div:jqmData(wrapper="true").ui-page-active').attr('id') );
console.log( $('div:jqmData(wrapper="true").ui-page-active').attr('data-url') );
```

Both return the correct *id* and *data-url*, so the elements must exist.

**EDIT2**:
I can query for the attribute *data-url* which gives me the correct value. However, I cannot select using this attribute like so:

```
$('div[data-url="'+$currentEntry+'"]').length
```

which gives me **0**

Comment: Well, does the HTML element you're looking for exist?

Comment: Probably not the problem, but are you aware `$activePage` is a global variable?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - good point! Checking, too.

Comment: It could be that the `:jqmData(url="...")` selector doesn't work on the iPad...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - hm... I'm not fond of this data-url anyway. Let's try attr()

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - sorry. $('div[data-url="'+$currentEntry+'"]').length is also 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to admit that I am blind-guessing, but you should try:

```
$activePage = $('div').filter(function(){return $(this).jqmData('url') === $currentEntry})
```

BTW, just for semantics i think "$currentEntry" shouldn't start with a dollar sign if it is not a jQuery object.

Comment: Ok. Will try without "$" and your suggestion. Thanks so far!

Comment: Quick question. If I wanted to make this into a standalone function (I need to call this a lot), how would that look like, if would call the function and pass in the respective currentPage as parameter?

Comment: You could use
`jQuery.fn.filterjm = function(currentEntry){
    return this.filter(function(){return $(this).jqmData('url') === currentEntry}
}`
And then you just use it like
`$("div").filterjm(currentEntry)`

Comment: BTW; the reason this works is probably because $currentEntry contains characters wich jQuery is unable to parse as a selector; maybe it contains quotes or other illegal character; so instead of using the jQuery parser i just use directly the filter method; wich BTW is the one that jQuery internally uses to apply non-native selectors (such as :jqm)